# How to mantain session in the same browser with Keycloack and Angular?

Tags: angular, keycloak

I am using Keycloack with Angular.

I would like to open a new tab (window.open(...)) but I have to log in again with Keycloak. I want to open the app directly.

Could you help me?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the token of the login into the localStorage of the Browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', tokenFromKeycloack);
```

In order to get the value of the value of token use :

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
```

and clear the localStorage when user is signed out by using:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

or remove the token by using:

```
localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I have several questions. Where Do i implement that code, in main.ts?

Comment: Add the code where you are getting the login token.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct single-sign-on. Just passing a Keycloak Token is not agood idea.
Have a look at the oidc lib for angular:
https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client

Comment: Please explain why this is not a good idea, as well as what "correct" is, and which part of the Angular OIDC library is pertinent to this question (and perhaps include those parts in your answer).